# Getting 'undefined symbol: cudnnCreate' in Jupyter notebook, but not on commandline

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, keras

I am running sample deep network script using keras with tensorflow with a GPU. It's on ubuntu. Everything runs fine from the commandline; e.g., I can copy any example network into a python file and run it and have verified the GPU is being used.

Problem: I've started up a Jupyter notebook to play around with some scripts and now I get a notification that the notebook's kernel has died and the following error shows up in the log:

`F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:221] Check failed: s.ok() could not find cudnnCreate in cudnn DSO; 
dlerror: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: undefined symbol: cudnnCreate`

I have a feeling that the notebook is having trouble finding the cuda libs. Are there some path variables that the notebook isn't getting? I have tried to set some using the os library (LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64, for example), so no avail.

Comment: The installation is a few months old. I'll take a look at upgrading tensorflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected, and as was suggested by Jonathan Hseu in a comment, my Jupyter notebook was using different environment variables than I was using from the commandline. Namely, my .bashrc file has the following line, which points to the proper cuDNN library:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64`

I (misguidedly) was running Jupyter notebook as a different user, so this environment variable was never getting set. Running it as myself, using my .bashrc, solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you didn't install cuDNN properly. Note that it's a separate installation step from CUDA:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn

Your command-line job probably doesn't rely on cuDNN (perhaps it's not using convolutions) so you don't get that failure.

Comment: The command line job is the exact code that fails in the jupyter notebook, which is definitely a CNN.

Comment: Yeah, the other possibility is that the notebook is getting different environment variables than running it in Python.

Comment: That was my suspicion.  I'll try a few things in that direction.

Comment: @JonathanHseu You can edit your answer and add that last comment there, it will be easier to find in the future.